# SignalR done event triggers too soon

Tags: signalr

SignalR is working fine on my dev machine and our dev test server, but when I deploy it to our acceptance test machine (Which should be identical configured like the dev test machine) I get a

> Uncaught Error: SignalR: Connection has not been fully initialized.
>   Use .start().done() or .start().fail() to run logic after the
>   connection has started.

I tracked the problem too that signalR is calling the done function too early before the connection is actually ready to be used

Has anyone had the same problem?

Full code can be found here
https://github.com/AndersMalmgren/SignalR.EventAggregatorProxy/blob/master/SignalR.EventAggregatorProxy.Client.JS/jquery.signalR.eventAggregator.js

Relevant code, constructor of class that handles all SignalR communication

```
var Proxy = function (eventAggregator) {
    this.eventAggregator = eventAggregator;

    this.hub = $.connection.eventAggregatorProxyHub;
    this.hub.client.onEvent = this.onEvent.bind(this);
    this.queueSubscriptions = true;
    this.queuedSubscriptions = [];
    $.connection.hub.start().done(this.onStarted.bind(this));
};
```

Im queuing all calls until done is called

```
onStarted: function () {
    this.queueSubscriptions = false;
    this.sendSubscribeQueue();
}
```

Done is however called directly (I think its actually called synchronously to the start function) and when the first message is sent I get the above message

**Solution:**

I found the problem, we are using MVC4 bundling, and the deploy script does not clear the target area before deploying. Thus there are multiple versions of signalR in the scripts folder, and the bundling framework loads them all. :D After fixing the deploy script things works as they should

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is fixed for the next release of SignalR.  The cause of the issue was that calling start multiple times caused the deferred object to instantly resolve.

Sooo how I'd fix your issue (if you don't want to wait for the next release) would be in your Proxy object I'd change the connection start line to do:

```
$.connection.hub.stateChanged(function(state) {
    // Transitioning from connecting to connected
    if(state.oldState === $.signalR.connectionState.connecting && state.newState === $.signalR.connectionState.connected) {
        // Start sending
    }
});

$.connection.hub.start();
```

This way you're protecting your library from user called "starts" and ONLY ever starting to send when connected.

Comment: Strange thing is we only call start once (The above constructor is only called once)

Comment: Hmm, I can't imagine why it would be triggering that early but there's been several additional fixes in the next release to address starting/stopping to ensure they're reliable.  You can always build the dev branch of SignalR and see if it fixes your issue :)

Comment: I found the problem, we are using MVC4 bundling, and the deploy script does not clear the target area before deploying. Thus there are multiple versions of signalR in the scripts folder, and the bundling framework loads them all. :D After fixing the deploy script things works as they should